# Making text transparent affect background color

Tags: html, css

Okay so i want to make a transparent button with some icon / text inside that, on hover, makes the text transparent and the background colored. This is "kinda" my code:

```css
.button-color {
  padding: 12px 20px;
  border: none;
  color: red;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.button-color:hover {
  color: transparent;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<button class="button-color">Hi!</button>
```

(The code is way longer but you get the point)
And this is the result:

Unhovered:

[image: Unhovered]

Hovered:

[image: Hovered]

I want the background to get transparent where the icon is. Oh and setting the icon to a certain color won't do the trick because these buttons are inside a 3D viewer that has a model loaded . I don't even know if this is achievable with pure css but who knows.

Comment: Please provide a full runnable example with code sandbox or using Stackoverflow snippets.

Comment: does not work the way you think iut work. Its logically impossible. Image that you have a black sheet of paper. If you write with a white pencil on it, you have no issue. If you write with transparent ink, you wont see anything then the black sheet of paper.  The invisible ink does not make the blacksheet of papaer disappear. Same for the website. Invisible text-color does not make the background disappear. For that you have to work with pseudoelements, SVG or clip-path to actually cut the background away. Alternativly mask it  to have it look alike.

Comment: Eseiast solution would be to use as text-color the grey-color that is used as background for the parent element.

Comment: @tacoshy Okay, any idea is welcomed on how to do it. I'm not against using clip path or something like that. Does exist any way to kinda filter the background? Like in photoshop, thinking of it like layers.

Comment: @tacoshy Can't do that  because of this: [image](https://imgur.com/a/ZiOR5Fb) , it has to be transparent...

Comment: It is possible but it's not that easy. You can read article [Cutting out the inner part of an element using clip-path](https://css-tricks.com/cutting-inner-part-element-using-clip-path/) by Ana Tudor. When you give up, think of another effect.

Comment: It is probably doable. But you should post a minimum snippets, a @AbdulrahmanAli says

Comment: @vals Done, its a minimal product but i think we get the idea.

Comment: Reopened because the answer provided as "duplicate" will only work if the background is an image. and this is not the case of the OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this effect using blend-mode : hard-light as long as the color of the element has RGB values that are 0 or 255. (that is, primary colors).

With this blend-mode, gray (RGB values of 128) is "transparent"

```css
.button-color {
  padding: 12px 20px;
  border: none;
  font-size: 100px;
  color: red;
  background-color: gray;
  mix-blend-mode: hard-light;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  width: 200px;
}
.button-color:hover {
  color: gray;
  background-color: red;
}

.container {
    background-color: lightgreen;
    width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<button class="button-color">Hi!</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Very nice trick! This is more similar to what I want to achieve. I'm gonna mark it as the most helpful!